# Meaning of "fly" as an adjective?

Tags: meaning, literature

In Jean Rhys's short story "The Lotus" (published in the collection [*Tigers Are Better-Looking*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tigers_Are_Better-Looking) in 1968), I found the following piece of dialogue (emphasis added):

> 'Sarcastic, isn't she? A dainty little thing, but sarcastic.' Lotus got up, swayed and held on to the mantlepiece. 'Are you a mother, dear?'
>
> 'Do you mean me?'
>
> 'No, I can see you're not — and never will be if you can help it. **You're too fly, aren't you?** (...)'

I couldn't find "fly" as an adjective in [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fly) or [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fly).

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fly#Adjective) provides the following meanings:

1. (*slang, dated*) Quick-witted, alert, mentally sharp.
2. (*slang*) Well dressed, smart in appearance.
3. (*slang*) Beautiful; displaying physical beauty.

Based on the story, the first meaning makes most sense. Can anybody confirms this?

Comment: *fly* in this context means, hip / trendy. I am just in passing so haven't got the time to look up a reference, but yes that's what it means. Happy New Year, by the way!

Comment: Here's a relatively modern pop interpretation of the word... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QtTR-_Klcq8

Comment: Speaker means addressee is too *alert, mentally sharp* to "accidentally" get pregnant and/or to devote her life to bringing up children. It wouldn't make much sense to say someone is too "attractive" to be a mother.

Comment: I've always seen 'fly' as carrying a pejorative flavour, so more calculating, scheming, streetwise than say 'shrewd''s denotation.

Comment: It's defined in Oxford: _North American_ Fashionably attractive and impressive. ‘a fly dude’ https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fly

Answer (score 2):

The passage can be rephrased as:-

Do you have children? No, I can see you're not — and never will be if you can help it. You're too fly, aren't you?

I see that as meaning being streetwise, knowing what is what and being prepared to deal with things. A slightly different take on definition 1.

on https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fly

you will find this definition of fly

fly
1. mod. knowledgeable; alert and in the know. This dude is fly; there’s no question about it.
2. mod. nice-looking; stylish. I like your fly shoes, Sam.
McGraw-Hill's Dictionary of American Slang and Colloquial Expressions Copyright © 2006 by The McGraw-Hill Companies, Inc. All rights reserved.